# jackson serialize referenced object fields to root

Tags: jackson

I am working on POC of jersey REST service to be consumed by js MVC framework. On one of the forms i need to return UserProfile object (serialized to JSON by Jackson) which will be used to pre-populate HTML form. On form submission only a subset of fields must be sent to server (since some fields like "role" are read-only and must not be changed) so input JSON will be mappped to UserProfileUpdateRequest object. From server-code maintenance point of view i would like to have have a relationship between these 2 objects, since UserProfileUpdateRequest will be a subset of UserProfile, so my first choice is to use composition: UserProfile contains UserProfileUpdateRequest.
The problem is that when UserProfile is serialized to JSON by jackson, all properties of referenced UserProfileRequest instance will be wrapped in userProfileRequest field- what seems to be quite natural but is not acceptable for JS guys (or at least i was told it is not acceptable). Is there any way i could force jackson to "flat" root object and point for which referenced objects its properties must be serialized under root? A little example

```
class UserProfileRequest{
private String a;
private String b;
...
}

class UserProfile{
private String role;
...
private UserProfileRequest userProfileRequest;
}
```

So when UserProfile is serialized i got:

```
{"role":"admin",...,"userProfileRequest":{"a":"...","b":"...",...}}
```

but would like to get

```
{"role":"admin",...,"a":"...","b":"...",...}
```

I am using Jackson 1.9.7.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [@JsonUnwrapped](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) annotation.

```
class UserProfile{
    private String role;
    ...
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private UserProfileRequest userProfileRequest;
}
```

Edit: Here is the link to [@JsonUnwrapped in Jackson 1.9.9](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonUnwrapped.html), so it should be available in 1.9.7, too.